# How to get a numbered count of different items in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Im using the following powershell query to get a list of disks:

```
Get-NcDisk | Select-Object -Property  model | Sort-Object -Property Model -Descending | foreach {$_.model}
```

**It outputs like below:**

X316_SMKRE06TA07
X316_HARIH06TA07
X316_HARIH06TA07
X316_HARIH06TA07

**How can I get it to output a numbered count of each type of disk like below:**

1 X316_SMKRE06TA07
3 X316_HARIH06TA07

Comment: Maybe this netapp community article will help you out with the problem you want to solve.
[NetApp_Community](https://community.netapp.com/t5/Microsoft-Virtualization-Discussions/Get-the-netapp-cluster-mode-count-and-the-total-sizeper-disks-type/td-p/126511)

Asulliva gives an answer there with a count of the disks.
Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for that - ill use it to expand out what im looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) will do this for you..

I can't use `Get-NcDisk` but it may just be:

```
Get-NcDisk | Select-Object -ExpandProperty model | Group-Object
```

Example output using a string array:

```
"X316_SMKRE06TA07","X316_HARIH06TA07","X316_HARIH06TA07","X316_HARIH06TA07" | Group-Object

Count Name                      Group                                                         
----- ----                      -----                                                         
    1 X316_SMKRE06TA07          {X316_SMKRE06TA07}                                            
    3 X316_HARIH06TA07          {X316_HARIH06TA07, X316_HARIH06TA07, X316_HARIH06TA07}
```

Comment: Perfect - I just added select count,name at end as well, cheers